# Force http- NOT https with htaccess with NO SSL activated

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I understand this might be a funny question since I am a newbie in this area...

I need to force a website to open on http:// and NOT https:// on a server where NO SSL is active (I do not yet have a valid certificate). Is this even possible and how (using .htaccess?)

I have already tried the below codes but as my hosting provider has explained to me, these would only work if a valid SSL certificate would be in place (on VPS).

The problem is that I can only get the certificate in a week and in the meantime, search engines that have already indexed my page as https:// are now opening it as such which only displays "this site cannot be reached" (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). I would like to temporarily force all such "bookmarks" and indexes to be redirected to the http:// address (which works perfectly).

The closest I came was with this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356019/how-to-force-http-not-https-using-htaccess) but even here, Tamás Bolvári pointed out that: "This doesn't work, if the HTTPS version doesn't have a valid cert. (Because browsers' cert alerts always come BEFORE Apache rewrites.) – Tamás Bolvári Feb 20 '17 at 8:36" Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Thank you so much for your (any) input.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain-name.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: In short: It cannot be done since the redirect from HTTPS to HTTP gets issued only after a successful TLS handshake. No successful TLS handshake (because of no or invalid certificate) means no redirect. There is no way around it except installing a valid certificate.

Comment: Steffen, thanks. I was kinda afraid of that...